# Reactjs Listen for scroll end events

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web, scroll

I'm working on a small application and I'm wondering how can I listen for the *end* of the scroll event.

I know that the following code allows me to listen for scroll events, but in my case I'm looking for a way to trigger an event once the user stops scrolling.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  (!this.state.showScrollWidget) ? this.setState({showScrollWidget: true}) : null;
})
```

If anyone has an idea about the best way to do it I will appreciate the help, otherwise if there is any third party library that may do the job I will also appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe a interval function should help, which would check last position of scroll and current position of scroll, if they are same, then it means user is not scrolling. What library are you planning to use though?

Comment: yeah I know that I can do that through an interval function but I was wondering if there is any better solution, concerning the library i'm waiting for some suggestions.

Comment: Nope. Just use a `setTimeout()`. There's no point in using another library for something so trivial (if one even exists - which I doubt).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there's any event to notify you that the scrolling stopped. In general, you need to wait for some time to elapse until the last scroll event. Typically you would use the debounce operation for that - many different utility libs implement it, e.g. lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce):

```
window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  _.debounce(() => {
    console.log("scrolling stopped");
  }, 1000)
);
```

Answer (score 11):

Solved the problem by using `lodash debounce`.

1. Attach `onScroll` event:

```
 <List onScroll={e => handleScroll(e)}/>
```

2. `useMemo` for the `endScroll` function:

```
 const handleEndScroll = useMemo(
    () =>
      _.debounce(() => console.log("END SCROLL"), 1000),
    []
  );
```

3. Handle scroll and endScroll:

```
 const handleScroll = e => {
    console.log("scroll scroll scroll");
    handleEndScroll();
  };
```

**Note:**

- install and import `lodash`
- import `useMemo`

Answer (score 4):

The `scrollend` event was added to FF in 109. Blink/Webkit browsers are expected to get it in mid- to late 2023.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollend

Comment: Not supported in Safari or Safari for iOS as of March 2024